# Adding data from multiple Excel files to two lists

Tags: python, file-system, excel

I have 5 nested `for` loops below, to add rows of data from multiple files to one of two lists.  Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?  I've come across an iterator-generator method named `iteritems()` -- could this be used to make this code more pythonic?

```
# 5 nested loops

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(src):
   files = [ _ for _ in files if _.endswith('.xlsx') ]
   for file in files:
     wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(root,file))
     worksheets = wb.sheet_names()
     for worksheet_name in worksheets:
         if worksheet_name.rfind('7600') != -1 :
            sheet = wb.sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)
            keys = [sheet.cell(3, col_index).value for col_index in xrange(sheet.ncols)]
            for row_index in xrange(4, sheet.nrows):
               d = {keys[col_index]: sheet.cell(row_index, col_index).value
                  for col_index in xrange(sheet.ncols)}
               if file.rfind('oam') != -1 :
                  list_7600EoX.append(d)
               else:
                   list_7600EoX_OAM.append(d)
```

Comment: It may be an indication that you should write your own class and wrap things inside it. Or separate responsibilities to different functions.

Comment: When confronted with situations like this, I frequently break inner loops out into separate functions. But I feel that we might need to know more to suggest a specific solution. What's your end goal?

Comment: It's a bit gnarly.  You can remove one level of nesting by using `glob` instead of the outer two loops.  And you can avoid the extra indentation of that first conditional by inverting the logic:  `if worksheet_name.rfind('7600') == -1: continue`

Comment: @wim Can `glob` really be told to go through all subdirectories? How?

Comment: No, sorry, glob can't do that.  Seems I was talking rubbish   :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is not with 5 (or more) loops. Your problem is that you mixing code of different nature: walking over filesystem and name matching, and processing of files into single chunk of code.

Separate it into different functions calling each other:

```
def process_worksheet(wb, worksheet_name):
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)
    # ...

def process_xslx(path):
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    worksheets = wb.sheet_names()
    for worksheet_name in worksheets:
        if worksheet_name.rfind('7600') != -1 :
            process_worksheet(wb, worksheet_name)

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(src):
    files = [ _ for _ in files if _.endswith('.xlsx') ]
    for file in files:
        process_xslx(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Another option is to use generators to hide some details on how iteration is performed. For example, instead of walking over filesystem, let generator yield workbooks:

```
def walk_xlsx(src):
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(src):
        files = [ _ for _ in files if _.endswith('.xlsx') ]
        for file in files:
            wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(root, file))
            yield wb

for wb in walk_xlsx(src):
    # filter() is also a generator which yields only 
    # worksheet names that have '7600' in their names 
    worksheets = filter(lambda wn: '7600' in wn, wb.sheet_names())
    for worksheet_name in worksheets:
        # ...
```

Comment: That's definitely a lot more readable than the code in the OP. :)

Comment: This does look a lot better. But I would say that five loops is a likely problem under any circumstances -- even if the loops are all doing things of the same nature. Loops alone add cognitive load. Linus says no more than [three](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) indentations total! That's two loops per function (because functions are already indented once). There's no _hard_ limit but a _firm_ maximum of four is a good rule of thumb.

Comment: @myaut  Thanks!  This is great and exactly the feedback I was hoping for.  Using functions makes a lot of sense to simply my code and I like the option using generators to further hide some details.  Cool stuff!   I'm also read the response from Kyle and I need to determine if it makes sense to combine his recommendation to use Pandas with yours -- I don't know if it simplifies things much more.

Comment: This alone is pretty simple and gets the job done. I'd only refactor it to using pandas if you end up doing a bunch more columnar and row operations. Pandas gives great power but takes some wrapping your head around.

Comment: I've been trying to use the generator approach, however, i can't seem to determine how to pass the file name from the generator so that I can use my logic "if file.rfind('oam') != -1" under "for worksheet_name in worksheets:".

Comment: @JimDurkin: You may yield tuples of values. I.e. `yield file, wb` in generator and `for file, wb in walk_xlsx(src)` in caller.

Answer (score 6):

As senderle mentions in the comments, one way to flatten things like this is to put the body of each `for` loop into a function. This makes the code slightly slower, due to the overhead of calling functions, but it does make it easier to read, not just because of the reduced indentation, but also because it's more modular, so it becomes more obvious what variables are being affected by each section of the code.

In some cases it's possible to flatten nested loops by using the [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.product) method, but that's not applicable in your case.

As the docs say:

> Equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example,
>   product(A, B) returns the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in B).

You need to pass all of the iterables to `product` when you call it, but in your program those iterables only become known as you descend into the loops.

But anyway, for future reference, here's a short Python 2 demo:

```
from itertools import product

r1 = (0, 1, 2)
r2 = (0, 10, 20)
r3 = (0, 100, 200)
for v3, v2, v1 in product(r3, r2, r1):
    print '%3d + %2d + %1d = %3d' % (v3, v2, v1, v3 + v2 + v1)
```

**output**

```
  0 +  0 + 0 =   0
  0 +  0 + 1 =   1
  0 +  0 + 2 =   2
  0 + 10 + 0 =  10
  0 + 10 + 1 =  11
  0 + 10 + 2 =  12
  0 + 20 + 0 =  20
  0 + 20 + 1 =  21
  0 + 20 + 2 =  22
100 +  0 + 0 = 100
100 +  0 + 1 = 101
100 +  0 + 2 = 102
100 + 10 + 0 = 110
100 + 10 + 1 = 111
100 + 10 + 2 = 112
100 + 20 + 0 = 120
100 + 20 + 1 = 121
100 + 20 + 2 = 122
200 +  0 + 0 = 200
200 +  0 + 1 = 201
200 +  0 + 2 = 202
200 + 10 + 0 = 210
200 + 10 + 1 = 211
200 + 10 + 2 = 212
200 + 20 + 0 = 220
200 + 20 + 1 = 221
200 + 20 + 2 = 222
```

Answer (score 3):

The smallest components (which could be the very last, very spreadsheet specific operations) should certainly be broken up into a function so that:

- It's easier to read
- Easier to unit test

However, looking over this code and the type of operations you're doing, you should try out [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/index.html) using its [read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.excel.read_excel.html).

Additionally, some of the things you want to be done you can do as separate loops or comprehensions to filter out things you don't want.

Example with the two combined:

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(src):
  filenames = [ os.path.join(root,_) for _ in files if _.endswith('.xlsx') ]
  for filename in filenames:

    # This returns a dict of DataFrames or a single DataFrame when only one sheet
    # TODO: Detect if single sheet vs. multiple sheet. This assumes multiple sheets
    dfs = pandas.io.excel.read_excel(filename) # If sheetname known, can be passed

    dfs = {name: df for (name, df) in dfs if '7600' in name}

    df = dfs[name]

    # DataFrame operations for the rest...
```

Beyond that, I also noticed you used rfind just to check for the existence of a string. You might as well use `in`: `'7600' in name`.